# Multiply all values of two vectors by each other

Tags: rust

hope someone could help me out a bit. I am doing the project euler question where I need to find the largest palindrom by multiplying 2 three digit numbers.

My code below is working for me but I wonder if there is a more efficient way to solve the cross multiplying between two vectors. In my case I use the same vector `mul1` for two iterations  but the logic behind it is the same:

Here, `x` will be 9,99,999 etc. according to the amount of digits.

```
let mul1: Vec<i64> = (1..=x).collect();
let mut result:i64 = 0;
let mut index = 0;
loop{
    if  index >= mul1.len() {
        break result;
    }else{
        for elem in mul1.iter() {
            if elem*mul1[index]>result && is_palindrome(elem*mul1[index]){
                result = *elem*mul1[index];
            }
        }
    }
    index+=1;
}
```

I wonder if this could be solved with using the zip, filter or map function which I dont fully understand right know ^^

Thank you for any advice!

Edit: As mentioned in the comments: [itertools::cartesian_product()](https://docs.rs/itertools/latest/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.cartesian_product)
is the way to go for that! Apparently the term for this calculation is called

> cartesian product

Thanks again!

Comment: Since you already have a solution, this is probably more fitting for [rust Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rust). Please provide a more complete example.

Comment: alright, just posted it there. Thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: If you actually use two slices you can use [`itertools::cartesian_product()`](https://docs.rs/itertools/latest/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.cartesian_product) to iterate over every combination of both iterators.

Comment: Hey thank you very much. Thats exactly what I was looking for!